# Logarithmic test for absolute convergence (questions on proof)

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

I am having issues understanding this proof. Questions outlined below...

**Thm [The Logarithmic Test]**

Suppose that $a_k \neq 0$ for large k and that $p= \lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{log(1/|a_k|)}{logk} $ exists as an extended real number. If $p >1$, then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ converges absolutely. If $p<1$, then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|a_k|$ diverges.

**pf:** Suppose that $p>1$. Fix $q \in (1,p)$ and choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k \geq N$ implies $log(1/|a_k|)>qlog k = log (k^q)$. Since the logarithm function is monotone increasing, it follows that $\frac{1}{|a_k|} > k^q$; that is, that $|a_k|<k^{-q}$ for $k \geq N$. Hence, by comparison test, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|a_k|$ converges.

Similarly, if $p<1$, then $|a_k|>1/k$ for large k. Hence, by the comparison test, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|a_k|$ diverges.

---

**questions**

**1)how did we get to assume such a k exists (from the first line of the proof)? isn't that what we're trying to prove?**

**2)where did the q come from (on the second line of the proof)?**

**3)We know that $|a_k|<k^{-q}$, but doesn't that only show that $a_k \rightarrow 0$, not $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|a_k|$ converges?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)  how did we get to assume such a k exists (from the first line of the proof)? isn't that what we're trying to prove?**

**2)where did the q come from (on the second line of the proof)?**

If $p\gt 1$, then fix any $q$ between $1$ and $p$ (so that $p-q$ is positive). By limit definition, given $\epsilon =p-q$ there exists $N$ such that $k\ge N$ implies $|\frac{\log|a_n|^{-1}}{\log k}-p|\lt p-q$. It follows that $k\ge N\implies \frac{\log|a_n|^{-1}}{\log k}\gt q$. Can you take it from here?

**3)We know that $|a_k|<k^{−q}$, but doesn't that only show that $a_k\to0$, not $\sum_{k=1}^\infty|a_k| $converges?**

Note that $\sum_{k=N}^{N+n}|a_k|\lt\sum_{k=N}^{N+n}\frac 1{k^p}$. The sequence on RHS converges as in this case $p\gt 1$ so by comparison test the sequence $\sum_{k=1}^n|a_k|$ converges, which is as good as saying that the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k|$ converges. Therefore, $a_k\to 0$ as $k\to \infty$ is necessarily true in this case.

Comment: 2-yes.
3-got it.